# How to solve the problem that the f1 value goes down when restarting tensorflow training process?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow to train a model for classification problem. When I stop the training process and restart it again, the `f1` value of training goes down quickly and then goes up. I don't know if this situation will influence the final performance of my model. I can hardly find the answer about this question because I use the high level API of tensorflow, estimator.

My tensorflow version is 1.14.0, Python version is 2.7 and I am using CentOS 7

Here is the code of *model_fn* required in estimator API

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    '''The model function of the estimator
    '''
    # features,features_mask=features[0],features[1]
    # raise ValueError(features.shape)
    network_type = params['network']
    # network_type = config.network
    if network_type == 'onset':
        net_func = onset_network
        loss_func = ModelLoss.onset_loss
        metric_func = ConfigMetrics.onset_metrics
    elif network_type == 'pitch':
        net_func = pitch_network
        loss_func = functools.partial(ModelLoss.pitch_loss_weighted_velocity, 
            velocity_weights = params['velocity_weights'])
        metric_func = ConfigMetrics.pitch_metrics
    elif network_type == 'frame':
        net_func = frame_network
        loss_func = ModelLoss.frame_loss
        metric_func = ConfigMetrics.frame_metrics
    elif network_type == 'union':
        net_func = union_network
        loss_func = ModelLoss.model_loss
        metric_func = ConfigMetrics.model_metrics

    logits = net_func(features, (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN), True) 
    # the prediction part
    probs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
    predictions = {
        'probs': probs,
    }

    # restore the parameters from the specific model file path. 
    restore_hook = RestoreHook(params['weight_path'], ['global_step'])
    if params['weight_path']:
        # restore parameters from two models -- onset and onset_pitch and frame
        model_paths = [x for x in params['weight_path'].split(',') if len(x) != 0]
        if len(model_paths) >= 2:
            tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(model_paths[0],
                {'onset/': 'onset/'})
            tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(model_paths[1],
                {'pitch/': 'pitch/'})
            if len(model_paths) == 3:
                tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(model_paths[2],
                    {'frame/': 'frame/'})

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions=predictions,
            prediction_hooks = [restore_hook])


    # the train part
    loss = loss_func(labels, logits) + ModelLoss.regu_loss()

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
        lr = params['initial_learning_rate']

        # use google learning rate settings
        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
                    name='training',
                    loss=loss,
                    global_step=global_step,
                    learning_rate=lr,
                    learning_rate_decay_fn=functools.partial(tf.train.exponential_decay,decay_steps=20000,decay_rate=0.98,staircase=True),
                    clip_gradients=3.0,
                    optimizer='Adam')

    else:
        train_op = None

    # the evaluation part
    metrics = metric_func(labels, predictions['probs'])

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=metrics, 
        training_hooks=[restore_hook],
        evaluation_hooks=[restore_hook])
class RestoreHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    '''The Hook is used to restore the parameters from the saved model.
    For the estimator, if we want to restore the model's parameters from 
    the saved model which is specified by ourselves, we should use this 
    little tirck.
    Usage:
        in the model function 's return value tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec,
        add the training_hooks = [RestoreHook(weight_path, ['global_step'])]
    '''
    def __init__(self, weight_path, exclude):
        '''prepare the saved mode path and the var_list that won't restore
        Args:
            weight_path: str, model file path. It can contains one or more models.
            exclude: list, variable list that wont be restored.
        '''
        if weight_path:
            self.model_paths = [x for x in weight_path.split(',') if len(x) != 0]
            self.var_list = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(
                exclude=exclude)
            if len(self.model_paths) == 1:
                self.init_fn = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
                        self.model_paths[0], self.var_list, ignore_missing_vars=True)
            else:
                self.init_fn = None
        else:
            self.init_fn = None
    def after_create_session(self, session, coord=None):
        if session.run(tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()) == 0:
            if self.init_fn:
                self.init_fn(session)
```

Here is the picture showing the situation:
[image]
The whole model code is very large, so I cannot provide the code to reimplement this situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally speaking, you should avoid posting links to code - try to boil the problem down to a [mcve] before asking, and include that code in your answer using the [built in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), *not* as a link.